# OpenCart order not executed 503

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart

I have several sites in OpenCart. One main, and the rest created manually. Those that are created manually give an error when ordering and `order_id` is zero. I created them this way: by import of an already created site and its directory files (`../system/storage`). Please tell me how to fix this error.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*/system/storage* is a storage folder with temporary files.

Folders */system/storage/cache* and */system/storage/modification* should be cleared inside after you creating a copy (only empty index.html should exist there). The files in these folders system will create by itself.

If you are creating a copy - cope the root folder with *admin*, *catalog* etc, and all files in it (*.htaccess*, *index.php*, *config.php* etc.). Copy database. Then change 2 config.php (in root directory and *admin*). Clear *cache* and *modification* in */system/storage*. Everything should work fine.

About a last screenshot -  go to phpMyAdmin and make sure that column is set to `auto increment` and the other settings are correct.

Comment: /system/storage/cache and /system/storage/modification I cleared. [image](https://i.imgur.com/AakbQLK.jpg) Files were not created automatically, no content. _.htaccess, index.php, config.php_ initially configured automatically.
config.php `define('DIR_CACHE','/var/www/test/data/www/test/system/storage/'.$this_dir.'/cache/');` etc..Config sites in my config.json

Comment: I'm not sure that you creating a copy of the sties  properly. To made a copy - you should copy all root folder, not just /system/storage/. Have you copy like this? Please, describe what your copy it consists of?

Comment: What other folders are needed? I have the following contents in the _storage_ folder: cache, download, logs, modification, upload. I did not copy other folders. Can this problem be in the database?

Comment: Opencart core folder contains admin, catalog, images, system and some files. You should copy all of them. Did you copy only storage? storage is only temporary files.

Comment: I copied only the folder _storage_

Comment: As i said - storage is only a few temporary files. You have to copy all root folder (admin, catalog, images system and add files from root), copy database, and change configs (in root and admin). Standalone *storage* is nothing.

Comment: I have problems with the "oc_order" table, when I try to create something in this table, I get an error: #1449 - The user specified as a definer ('tmp_8e1818c097ff'@'localhost') does not exist

Comment: On the copy or original site? make a correct copy and there will be no errors

Comment: I have an ISP panel and I create a database there and dump

Comment: You have to copy all root folder (admin, catalog, images system and add files from root), copy database, and change configs (in root and admin). Have you done all off that? Do you have an external link to your project so k can see it?

Comment: Solved the problem, made a separate dump table "oc_order". Thanks for the help!